# Python `multiprocessing` spawned process using base Python, not virtualenv Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, virtualenv, python-embedding

On a standard installation of python (e.g. via miniconda), I run [this script (also pasted below)](https://gist.github.com/goretkin/f6d84b2ae824bb17a29455eda4eb1789) and I get the following output:

```
python test_python_multiprocessing.py
arg1: called directly
sys.executable: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python3_7_4\python.exe
-----

arg1: called via multiprocessing
sys.executable: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python3_7_4\python.exe
-----

The two exes:
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python3_7_4\python.exe
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\python3_7_4\python.exe
```

This is what I expect.

When I run the *same* script from a python from a virtual environment whose base is a python embedded in [a scriptable application](https://www.ansys.com/products/embedded-software/ansys-scade-suite), I get the following result:

```
arg1: called directly
sys.executable: C:\[virtual_environment_path]\Scripts\python.exe
-----

arg1: called via multiprocessing
sys.executable: C:\[application_with_python]\contrib\Python37\python.exe
-----

The two exes:
C:\[virtual_environment_path]\Scripts\python.exe
C:\[application_with_python]\contrib\Python37\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test_python_multiprocessing.py", line 67, in <module>
    test_exes()
  File ".\test_python_multiprocessing.py", line 64, in test_exes
    assert exe1 == exe2
AssertionError
```

Crucially, the child `sys.executable` does not match the parent `sys.executable`, but instead matches the base of the parent.

I suspected that the python that ships with the application had been altered, perhaps to have the spawned process point to a hard-coded python path.

1. I have taken a look at the python standard libraries that ship with the application, and I do not find any discrepancy that explains this difference in behavior.
2. I tried manually setting the executable to what the default should be before `multiprocessing.Process` with `multiprocessing.set_executable(sys.executable)` or `multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").set_executable(sys.executable)`. These do not have an effect.

What are possible explanations for the difference in behavior between a standard python installation, and this python that is embedded within a scriptable application? How can I investigate the cause, and force the correct python executable to be used when spawning child processes?

`test_python_multiprocessing.py`:

```py
import multiprocessing

def functionality(arg1):
    import sys
    print("arg1: " + str(arg1))
    print("sys.executable: " + str(sys.executable))
    print("-----\n")
    return sys.executable

def worker(queue, arg1):
    import traceback
    try:
        retval = functionality(arg1)
        queue.put({"retval": retval})
    except Exception as e:
        queue.put({"exception": e, "traceback_str": traceback.format_exc()})
        raise
    finally:
        pass

def spawn_worker(arg1):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue, arg1,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    
    err_or_ret = queue.get()

    handle_worker_err(err_or_ret)
    if p.exitcode != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("Subprocess failed with code " + str(p.exitcode) + ", but no exception was thrown.")
    return err_or_ret["retval"]

def handle_worker_err(err_or_ret):
    if "retval" in err_or_ret:
        return None
    err = err_or_ret
    #import traceback
    if (err is not None):
        #traceback.print_tb(err["traceback"]) # TODO use e.g. tblib to get traceback
        print("The exception was thrown in the child process, reraised in parent process:")
        print(err["traceback_str"])
        raise err["exception"]

def test_exes():
    exe1 = functionality("called directly")
    exe2 = spawn_worker("called via multiprocessing")

    print("The two exes:")
    print(exe1)
    print(exe2)

    assert exe1 == exe2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_exes()
```

[EDIT] the fact that I detected the issue on a python embedded in the scriptable application is a red-herring. Making a virtual environment with a "standard install" Python 3.7.4 base also has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long story short, using the "virtual" interpreter causes bugs in multiprocessing and the developers decided to redirect virtualenv environments to the base one.
[link to issue 35797](https://bugs.python.org/issue35797)

and this is pulled from [popen_spawn_win32.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py)

```py
# bpo-35797: When running in a venv, we bypass the redirect
# executor and launch our base Python.
```

one solution is to use `subprocess` instead, and connect to your "pipes" through a socket to a manager instead of using multiprocessing, you can see how to connect to a manager using a socket in [BaseManager documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager), python makes it as simple as plugging in its port number.

you can also try [pathos](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/) as its multiprocessing implementation is "different", (i think its pools use sockets, but i didn't dig in it before and it has other problems from the way it spawns new workers differently, but it can work in a few weird environments where multiprocessing fails.)

Edit: another nice parallelizing alternative that actually uses sockets is [Dask](https://www.dask.org/get-started), but you have to start the workers separately, not through its built-in pool.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers. It certainly seems related. Am I correct in understanding that this issue is fixed in the latest versions of Python? I do not see it occurring in Python 3.9.12 but I do see it in Python 3.7.4.

Comment: I see that the bug is documented at fixed in CPython 3.7.3: https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-7-3-release-candidate-1